# Use of undeclared identifier in header file (Clang)

Tags: c++, function, shared-libraries, clang, header-files

I am creating a function to read the contents of a file, located in an IO.cpp file:

```
#include "IO.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
IO::IO()
{
    //ctor
}

void IO::readFile(std::string fileName)
{
    std::ofstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open(FileName);
    inputFile >> fileName.toStdString;
    inputFile.close();
    std::cout << fileName;
}
```

With the header file IO.h:

```
#ifndef IO_H
#define IO_H


class IO
{
    public:
        IO();
        void readFile(std::string inputFile);
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // IO_H
```

But I get an error from Clang that says

> include/IO.h|9|error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'|

And I can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: You didn't include <string> in IO.h

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When parsing the header (specifically the `void readFile(std::string inputFile);` line), the compiler doesn't know an `std` namespace exists, much less `string` exists inside that namespace.

`#include <string>` in the header.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases this occurs when you forget to include `#include <iostream>` on implementation of methods on a separate file i.e. outside main function (i.e. when you go header file route)